# how to select several option from multi Select listbox using vba-selenium

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

I want to select several options from a multi select list box using vba-selenium.

I have google it but can't find how to do it in vba code.
I have tried many things but can't be successful.
Please help me out.

Below is my webpage:

```
<select name="select" id="select_id" multiple="multiple> 
<option value="value1"> some-value1 </option> 
<option value="value2"> some-value2 </option> 
<option value="value3"> some-value3 </option> </select>
```

I just want to know how do we select multiple options at a time using vba- selenium. For e.g. In the above selecting "some-value1", "some-value2" at a same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to hold the Control key just like a real user would do:

```
Private Assert As New Selenium.Assert
Private Keys As New Selenium.Keys

Private Sub Handle_Multi_Select()
  Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
  driver.Get "http://odyniec.net/articles/multiple-select-fields"

  Dim ele As WebElement
  For Each ele In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//select[@name='ingredients[]']/option")
    ele.Click Keys.Control
  Next

  driver.Quit
End Sub
```

The latest version:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for ur reply.
I have use this
`Dim ele As WebElement
  For Each ele In driver.findElementsByXPath("//select[@name='select']/option")
    ele.Click
    driver.SendKeys Keys.Control
Next`
But it does not work.
It traverse all elements one by one.
But i want to select some.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Drop the SendKeys and customize the xpath accordingly: "//select[@name='select']/option[@value='value1' or @value='value2']"

Comment: I have tried this      
    `Dim ele As WebElement    
    For Each ele In driver.findElementsByXPath("//select[@name='select']/option[@value='value1' or @value='value2']")    
    ele.Click`    
But it also select only one option.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please help me.
Thanks.